# Camel guaranteed delivery using Redis

Tags: redis, apache-camel

Can someone let me know how to do guaranteed delivery using camel-redis?

My use case is something like below:-

```
from("jetty:http://localhost:8888/hello").to("redis://...")
```

Once the message is written to redis send a success response to http client, so that the client is not blocked waiting for response.

Then in another route I want to process the message from redis like below and then deleting it from redis when the processing is successful

```
from("redis://...").to(...)
```

Comment: Good approach - it is called "store and forward" pattern.  See http://redis.io/commands/rpoplpush . What exacly is your issue with implementing the pattern?

Comment: How to handle the case when there an error after reading the message from redis in the path `from("redis://").to(...).to(...)` and the message is not delivered to the final destination? How to add the message back to the original list?

Comment: If I am using BRPOPLPUSH and there is no ack for a timeout then move the message back to the original list from the destination list. If there is an ack delete the message. Can you suggest what will be the best way to implement this using java dsl?

Answer (score 1):

Good approach - it is called "store and forward" pattern.

> and the message is not delivered to the final destination?

then - what about the "try/catch"? try to send the message and when fails, just put it back to the redis.

Usually this pattern is implemented using messaging (JMS), where the messaging is having some important features: the destination, the retry count, retry periode and the dead-letter queue, etc.

Using any simpler store (redis, jdbc, ...) you will have to implement these messaging features by yourself. (I must admin I am not good with Redis, but the same issue comes with using simple JDBC as a message store).

At least add the retry count and "next delivery timestamp". And what happens when the message is not delivered after predefined count - it's up to you - send a mail, write a log, stop the world..

Comment: Yeah `try/catch` is there. I was asking about the case if the camel instance go down after reading the message from redis.

Comment: Either if the endpoints (redis, http) are not fully transactional. In that case you won't have any perfect solution and you will have to compromise. You can use the redis transaction command or delete the redis object only when the service call is successful. In the later case the remote service should be idempotent.